# Copy content of one node into different content type

Tags: nodes

Does anybody know how to copy a content of one node from one content type into different content type?

Content type A -> Content type B

I would like to copy the contents from the fields of content type A similar to content type B and set it as default for content type B, but I would let users to edit the field. I can't do **node clone** because content type B has more fields than content type A and also each content has a different URL aliases.

I tried entity reference prepopulate but it doesn't meet my needs. Also tried cross clone but I'm loosing my brain because I can't get it to work by rules, no instruction.

Are there any available module I can use? if you have any other suggestions please be nice to a beginner. :)

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node Clone and Node Convert was almost perfect, but it did not support my needs perfectly.

I found [Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill). This module is way more simple and it allows me to get the content from 1 content type and be copied to another type of content instantly and be able to edit it all in one click.

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) module:

> Node Convert adds a menu tab "Convert" on the node view page, i.e. node/1/convert, which gives the ability to convert the node from its current node type to another node type. The module provides the means to transfer all the field values of the current node type into fields on the destination node type, or discard them.

Of course this does not clone, but you can use node clone to create a clone of the A content type, and then convert said clone to content type B.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use this with rules, as of now I'm having problem with my template because it's not showing the node clone. I'll get back to you if everything works well.